# Popen subprocess creates two processes

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen, kill

I am using this code to make a killswitch for my program

`killSwitch = Popen(['killswitch.exe', str(pid)])`

it feeds in the pid of the main thread, if the main thread becomes unresponsive i can use a keybind to kill it. However when closing normally, without running the killswitch, it never closes. So i need to handle the process, but using popen creates two processes and only reports back one, doing killSwitch.kill() doesn't work because one process is still left open. I also do not want to taskkill killSwitch.exe because if other instanaces are open i do not want to close the killSwitch for the other instances. Is there a way to make it so only one process opens or close both the processes?

Comment: How do you conclude that there are two processes?

Comment: There are two killswitch.exe files under the main thread in task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using

`os.system(f'taskkill /f /t /pid {killSwitch.pid}')`

This kills the whole process tree although I only have one pid without interrupting other instances.